# Argument is incompatible with a parameter of the same type

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I have been practicing writing CUDA code and learning the structure and ideals behind massively parallel programming. Anyways, I have come across a problem that I don't quite understand.

Here's the code:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

__global__ void cudaTest(struct led* input[])
{
    int ledNum = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
}

int main()
{
    struct led
    {
        unsigned char red, green, blue;
    };

    struct led* input[1200];
    struct led* dInput[1200];

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dInput, sizeof(struct led) * 1200);
    cudaMemcpy(dInput, input, sizeof(struct led) * 1200,     cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaTest<<<4, 300>>>(dInput);
    cudaMemcpy(input, dInput, sizeof(struct led) * 1200,    cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(dInput);

    printf("Input: %d", *input);

}
```

The issue I am coming across is upon compilation of the program:

testCuda.cu(22): error: argument of type "led **" is incompatible with parameter of type "led **"

```
cudaTest<<<4, 300>>>(dInput);
```

I don't understand this for obvious reasons... It says essentially the same thing isn't compatible with itself.

I don't know if this is a problem with how I am allocating the memory for the array, with how I am initializing it, or whatever it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just for some context, this code has no application, it is a test program that I use to test code before I implement it into my project. The goal of this program is simple, to allocate space for an array on the GPU, transfer it to the GPU, call the kernel, and transfer it back.

Comment: Sorry, removed the tag.

Comment: It is, but I see what he's saying, you need more than just knowledge of C to understand this.

Comment: @Olaf How is that not `related` to C??

Comment: @2501: Simply because CUDA is not C, but C++-based. Read the code carefully.

Comment: @WaffleMan0310: C and C++ are different languages. CUDA is C++ based!

Comment: @Olaf You should have replaced the tag with C++, not just remove the C tag.

Comment: @2501: It would be a good practice for OP (which he did). But actually as it adds extensions, the CUDA flag alone is the better variant.

Comment: Please format the message correctly. Also we don't see which is line 22 and you should not expect to count lines.

Comment: Sorry again, I'll put the line in below the error.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know what your `struct led` is when it first encounters it as a parameter type in your kernel function.  Therefore you need to define that struct type before you use it, even as a function parameter.  This construct you have would not work correctly in ordinary C or C++, so the underlying concept here is not specific to CUDA.

Additionally, for `dInput`, we don't create a host allocation for a pointer we intend to use as a device pointer.  So just declare the bare pointer and then use it in `cudaMalloc` to attach the device allocation to it.

try this instead of what you have:

```
 #include <cuda_runtime.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 struct led
 {
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
 };

 __global__ void cudaTest(led *input)
 {
    int ledNum = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    input[ledNum].red = 5;
 }

 int main()
 {

    led* input = new led[1200];
    led* dInput;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dInput, sizeof(struct led) * 1200);
    cudaMemcpy(dInput, input, sizeof(struct led) * 1200,     cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaTest<<<4, 300>>>(dInput);
    cudaMemcpy(input, dInput, sizeof(struct led) * 1200,    cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(dInput);

    printf("Input: %d", input[0].red);

 }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code without explanation what went wrong.

Comment: For one you were declaring a array of pointers to led structs.. instead of an pointer that points to an array of led that did not look like what you wanted to do.. I just posted the answer as a suggestion I did not have time to try is as I am working :)

Comment: I just hope this gets the conversation in the right direction for you to get your answer.

Comment: I've made a few edits which turn your answer into correct code and also to address the concern raised by @Olaf . If you object, feel free to roll the edits back.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: While I appreciate your edit, this makes it actually your answer, not Rob's. It is acceptable to help low-rep answerers, but with >1k7 reps, he really should know how it works and be able to provide correct and complete answers himself. Anyway, I'll remove the DV for now.

Comment: Its a team effort, Thank you @RobertCrovella for the edits. I did not have much time yesterday to put in the extra touches, but seeing as the bulk of the conversation were about semantics on how the question was tagged I figured throwing something to get the ball moving in the right direction was better than nothing. And you took it to the finish thank you. I would never roll back help :).